# Snapkit: How can I embed a simple tableView inside a scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I'm using Snapkit in my iOS project.

View -> ScrollView -> Tableview

I tried view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(tableView)

I tried setting a bunch of constraints on the tableview but it never shows up on the scrollview.
Whereas if I add it to the view (view.addSubview(tableView) ) then it shows up correctly.

Comment: what's your purpose when adding tableView as subview of a UIScrollView?

Comment: Need to display a list of items surrounded by few labels, buttons, etc

Comment: what is your size of table you want?
what is scroll direction of scrollView (horizontal, vertical)?

Comment: table width = 100%, height = as much required. scroll direction = vertical

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use an additional uiScrollView with these requirements, however you can check the answer

Comment: I would recommend using the table view header and footer instead of embedding it in a scroll view, but if you still want to do that you could use the `StiffTableView` class I talk about on [this article](https://savvyapps.com/blog/using-advanced-auto-layout-techniques-to-adapt-interfaces-to-screen-content-intrinsic-content-size-stack-views)

Answer (score 0):

```
    label.text = "hello world"
    scrollView.addSubview(label)
    scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
    }

    label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalTo(tableView.snp.top)
    }
    
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.height.equalTo(view)
    }
```

Comment: There are elements above and below the table. I don't want the height to be 100%. Can the height be equal to the natural height?

Comment: however I recommend you remove scrollView and set:
`table.tableHeaderView = label`

Comment: What about the element at the bottom?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, actually i don’t know what layout you want. For example, if table view isn’t scrolled to bottom, whether or not your label at the bottom should be shown?

Comment: And with my layout code, it shows table view, right? What is part it doesn’t fit your requirements?